# boost date time catching exception

Tags: c++, validation, date, boost-date-time

I'm trying to check if a date is valid using boost `date_time`. The documentation says it will throw an exception if the date is invalid. Now I've been trying to use try-catch if the date is indeed invalid but somehow my program still gets thrown out and stops..

simple test code:

```
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int year = 2013;
    int month = 1;
    int day = 50;

    try
    {
        boost::gregorian::date d(year, month, day);

        throw 20;
    }
    catch (int e)
    {
        std::cout << "error! date does not excist!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "error no: " << e << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

final question:
what is the proper way using date_time to validate a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::gregorian::date` throws `std::out_of_range` type exceptions when day, month or year are out of range.
Your catch block catches exception of `int` type. You need to use a catch block with type `std::out_of_range` to catch the specific exception.

Also, there is no need to use a `throw(20)` statement in your try block.

Comment: oops, I think I have to read the try/catch section again :p thanks!

Comment: btw, is this a proper method validating a date?